# How can get full path of file name in file upload control

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using asp.net fileupload control for uploading excel file from my system for exporting excel file to sql server. when i upload the file from my path, it only load filename  not a full path. i need full path to execute a excel file in the sql server stored procedure.because without full path stored procedure for excel not working for me. how can solve the problem?

This is my stored procedure that need full path of the excel file.so i need to get full path.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[sp_excelforgeneralholidays](@filname nvarchar(max),@getdate datetime,@adminid int)
 as  
 declare @datavar nvarchar(max)
 declare @sql varchar(1000)

 set @datavar  = 'Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filname

 set nocount on
  begin
  set @sql ='insert into Generalholyday_details(Date,Day,Reason) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'','''+@datavar+';HDR=YES'',''SELECT Date,Day,Reason FROM [Sheet1$]'')'
 exec (@sql)
  end
```

Comment: The file upload control gives you a copy of the file - which you can place wherever you like and then talk to SQL Server about it. But what it won't do is tell you where the file came from. The browsers don't supply that information because it would be a security issue.

Comment: If you want full path, you need to save the file first and then you can get the saved location.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever _"The browsers don't supply that information because it would be a security issue."_ - and useless, since the server can't do anything with the path, as that path points to a file on the client.

Comment: but this is my stored procedure to export  excel to sql

Comment: Side note: [Don't do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx): "We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using **sp_** as a prefix. SQL Server uses the **sp_** prefix to designate system stored procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system procedure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This.

```
string pth = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: No, I am only get the file name.

Comment: baskaran , you said **full path of filename** but now **filename only** . What do you need actually ?

Comment: I used above code but actually i got the following C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0\\generalholiday.xlsx" when run that code, but my file is in D:\

Comment: i don't understanding what u need. please explain.

Comment: Above I edited my question that contain the stored procedure for export excel file to sql server. I am using file upload control for getting excel file in asp.net. I have a excel file in D:\, but when i upload using this control as edited by your code it give the path as in the above comment.

Comment: You can't. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path. So u have to temporarily save the file in a folder then map the path as u need.

Comment: i Have corrected it will give u the exact location of file.              string pth = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: server.MapPath set the file path as my project file path name.but i have a excel file at c:\  in my system. so when I  want to upload a file  as C:\Gengeralholiday.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

try using this ....

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);

FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
```

Comment: how can get this saved file name in a string